# How to access result of cursor in MySQL when it is in form of list

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, cursor

I have created one procedure that returns me number of IDs

e.g. `DECLARE ex_cursor for SELECT table_name from table_list`

which will provide me List of tables for which I want to change the ID .

These IDs now I want to update, lets say ID = ID + 1 for that particular table.
and after this computation I want to store the value back to the table,

```
UPDATE table set ID = ID + 1
```

now what I am doing is that, 
I retrieved table_list from the cursor ex_cursor  and trying to write dynamic query and passing parameter of table in it, to update that particular table's ID.

```
OPEN ex_cursor ;
    BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT IN @temp
    LOOP:
        UPDATE @temp set ID = ID + 1
        FETCH NEXT IN @temp
    END LOOP;
    END;
```

This is brief on what I am trying to do, I have written complete procedure in MySQL but there is error for this looping part. After opening the cursor I can not loop through it. but I can not find what the error is.

What should I do? I don't want any other approach because all Three queries are dependent on each other.

Answer (score 1):

You must use prepared statements because `@temp` variable will no evaluate on direct a query. Also the loop format in MySQL is as follows:

```
DECLARE tmp_table_name varchar(50); 
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE; -- flag to determine the end of loop
declare ex_cursor cursor for /*put your sql cursor here*/;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE; -- event 

OPEN ex_cursor;
ex_loop: LOOP
    FETCH ex_cursor INTO tmp_table_name; -- must use a regular variable
    if done then
       leave ex_loop;
    end if;

    -- use prepard statement
    set @sql = concat('UPDATE ',tmp_table_name,' set ID = ID + 1;');
    PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt1;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

END LOOP;
```